# Opposite of jquery slice / select items outside of slice

Tags: jquery, slice

I have a javascript (jQuery) pagination system which works by hiding items on a page with filters applied with checkboxes.  It works fine, but I'm now trying to paginate this dynamic result-set, so I want to hide all items outside of a particular range.

The jQuery slice function looks kind of suitable for this, only it selects all items within the range.  What I want to do is the opposite of that.  I want to select all items outside of the range.

```
HTML: 
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
    <li>Item 6</li>
    <li>Item 7</li>
    <li>Item 8</li>
    <li>Item 9</li>
    <li>Item 10</li>
</ul>​

jQuery:
$(function(){
    $('li').slice(3,6).css('background','#f00'); 
});​
```

I've put together a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SLuXz/1/ - what I'd like to do is have items 1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9 and 10 show in red.  I know I could do this with two slices (0-3 and 7-10) but wondered if there was a neater way of doing it using something like 'not' or another core function.

Thanks for any pointers folks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since performance should be important to everyone, Dan's answer should definitely not the accepted answer since it is about three times as slow as using Kevin B's answer.

If we run this code

```
var Start =  new Date().getTime();
for(i = 0; i<10000; i++){
    //How Dan's answer suggests to do this
    var e = $('.elem').not($('.elem').slice(0,99));
}
var Finish = new Date().getTime();
console.log('Using selector filter',Finish-Start);

var Start =  new Date().getTime();
for(i = 0; i<10000; i++){
    //A better way to do Dan's answer, but still twice as slow 
    var o = $('.elem');
    var e = o.not(o.slice(0,99));
}
var Finish = new Date().getTime();
console.log('Using selector filter',Finish-Start);

Start =  new Date().getTime();
for(i = 0; i<10000; i++){
    //The fastest method
    var e = $('.elem').filter(function(i) { 
        return i < 0 || i > 99;
    });
}
Finish = new Date().getTime();
console.log('Using object filter',Finish-Start);
```

And watch the console, we get this output:

> Using selector filter 989
>
> Using selector filter 683
>
> Using object filter 349

Now this might not be too much of an issue in very low data usage, but in my case where I'm checking table rows that could amount to quite a bit, this would be very important.

Answer (score 2):

You can use .not() like this

```
$(function(){
    $('li').not($('li').slice(3,6)).css('background','#f00'); 
});​
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wirey00/CYVPh/)

Comment: Actually, I just got to the exact same thing!  Thanks.  Will accept as soon as it lets me.

Comment: There's a much faster solution to this, see mine or Kevin B's answer

Answer (score 2):

You could use `.filter` for this too:

```
$(function(){
    $("li").filter(function(i) { 
        return i < 3 || i > 5;
    }).css(...);
});
```

or

```
$(function(){
    $("li").filter(":lt(3),:gt(5)").css(...);
});
```

or (probably less efficient)

```
$(function(){
    $("li:lt(3),li:gt(5)").css(...);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CYVPh/1/

Comment: [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/:not/) same as [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/), but result inverted.